# How to do signature capture from wap device to PHP/MySQL website

Tags: php

How I can develop a php website for capture signature from Touch Screen PDA and smart phone.

1. I found Jquery plugin : http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/. will it help me to get signature capture from touch pad devices.
2. Do I need to write some code in Java or something else.

Kindly give your suggestions.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it in PHP. Save the signature output to a database, and then use the plugins regenerate function to output it where I needed to.

Mr. Bradley was nice enough to create a detailed PHP/MySQL tutorial, http://thomasjbradley.ca/articles/saving-signatures-php-mysql/

I hope this helps you.